# What is Twitter's definition of an URL?

Tags: api, twitter

I already asked the same question over at [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6640), however, I didn't get an answer there. So maybe someone here on SO ran into the same issue and has an answer.

In my application I count the length of the characters the user enters to compose a tweet. However, if the user enters an URL, this will be shortened automatically (by Twitter's API) when posting the tweet. So I have to replace the length of the URL with the length of the resulting t.co URL in my character counter.

However, the problem is now, what is Twitter's definition of an URL so that I know when you adapt my character counter and when not. For example www.verylongexampleurl.de gets shortened, while verylongexampleurl.de (without the www) doesn't, but verylongexampleurl.com does get shortened again.

I couldn't find any documentation, but maybe I missed it. All hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-url-wrapper):

> Need help parsing tweet text?
>
> Take a look on the Twitter text processing library we’re using for auto linking and extraction of usernames, lists & hashtags.
>
> Ruby: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb
>      Java: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-java
>      Javascript: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js

The actual specification (tests) can be found here: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-conformance/blob/master/autolink.yml

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. From the links provided I found this one: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-conformance/blob/master/autolink.yml which is exactly what I need.